# Unable to use $.get within WordPress page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to use an ajax $.get() request to display calculated data within one of my WordPress pages. I haven't decided if I'm going to host the php calculation file on a different server of mine, or the one that WordPress is hosted on (don't think this would make a difference anyway since its a data request). I'm looking to add the following code to either the header.php file, or even better, within the page created in wp-admin:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $.get("http://my-other-website.com/parse-list.php",function(data){
          alert(data);
      });
  });
</script>
```

I know this is a basic function, but I'm just really stumped on how it doesn't work within WordPress, but works when on my other server that doesn't host WordPress. I tested jQuery to make sure it was being loaded properly, with a simple alert("hey");, and the alert works just fine. Has anyone else had this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Open your console and check the network tab, what is the status of the request?

Comment: Also, check the console if there are any errors thrown. Is jQuery loaded? And if yes, note that the jQuery version that ships with WP by default is running on compatibility mode. Try wrapping your code in an anonymous function instead: http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 5):

jQuery in WordPress runs in noConflict mode which means the global $ shortcut for jQuery isn't available. Replace your code with the following:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $.get("http://my-other-website.com/parse-list.php",function(data){
          alert(data);
      });
  });
</script>
```